# How can i increase or decrease the size of any object drawn in UI View at run time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am creating a flowchart application where i can draw any shape, drag and position that shape anywhere in the `UIView`, I want to **increase/decrease** the size of shapes at run time. How can i increase or decrease the size of any object/shape drawn in `UIView` at run time?

Comment: What about UIView's transform property?

Comment: Christian, UIView's transform property is used for rotating the view.

Comment: And for just about anything an [affine transform matrix](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101) can do, including scaling, skewing and flipping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are pinch/zoom gestures that you can handle. You can then set the size of the view by setting it's `frame` property.